# how to make angular.js work with wowslider.js correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this code and i open it as a demo on plunk and this the link

[plnkr.co/edit/?s=VT0oyRJqkBCyyX1W](http://%20plnkr.co/edit/?s=VT0oyRJqkBCyyX1W)

why my images can not appear and take wow slider and script.js effects ?

Comment: You never initialized wow.slider in your code, please check the documentations on wow slider and how to initialize

Comment: you say that my problem in initialized wow slider in angular is that true ??

Comment: NO! you never added wowslider js code or initialize it anywhere in your html.

Comment: thanks i update my code but it still not work this is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/ZMqNnVwcGPDGBnTg81o1?p=catalogue&s=VT0oyRJqkBCyyX1W

Comment: I was asked about angular and wow slider

Comment: I know you asked about integration angular and wow slider but without initializing the  wow slider itself how can you expect it to work at first?

Comment: Firstly is your code working without angular? Try running that code without angular and only owl-slider then get back.

Comment: yes my code work perfectly with out angular , really i tried  my html code without angular and it work nice like this demo http://wowslider.com/angular-slider-collage-demo.html

Comment: wow slider has not free manual or doc

Comment: can you update my plnkr link

Comment: Here is the deal buddy wowslider loads before angular and searches for the dom elements and builds up the slider, but you are passing scope after the dom is built, and wowslider cannot detect that one way is to load wowslider after angular has rendered the scope, and by the way The link which you have provided, angular-slider is just a name its nothing related to angularjs. I suggest you to take a look at other alternatives which work nice with angular

Comment: good Stack leaner but how can i load wowslider after angular has rendered the scope

Comment: or what is the alternative which work nice with angular